# How to max utilize my laptop memory for runing pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I create a dataframe from 800M txt file and the df has 21.3 million rows. I installed pyspark 2.0.0 on my mac with 16GB memory. I have not modify any settings. 
I use 70% of df for training a mllib model and java heap memory came.
While I use 60% of df for training, it is ok and return me a model.

How can I max utilize my laptop for settings, to let me use 80% or more data for training ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `spark.driver.memory` for the driver program and `spark.executor.memory` for the spark executors. Which one is the right one depends on your application, but in your case I guess it is `spark.executor.memory`.

You can set this as a command line option to `spark-submit` and/or `pyspark`.

See [Apache Spark Memory Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties) for more information.